# creating kafka topic using spring @Bean?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Is it possible to create kafka topic using spring bean. Like we have Queue and TopicExchanges in RabbitMQ which can be created programmatically like these.

```
@Bean
Queue queue(){
  return new Queue("name");
}
```

Tried the documentation couldnt get much help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible now with the latest Spring Kafka version `1.3`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/1.3.0.RC1/reference/html/_reference.html#_configuring_topics.

```
@Bean
public KafkaAdmin admin() {
    Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>();
    configs.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
            StringUtils.arrayToCommaDelimitedString(kafkaEmbedded().getBrokerAddresses()));
    return new KafkaAdmin(configs);
}

@Bean
public NewTopic topic1() {
     return new NewTopic("foo", 10, (short) 2);
}
```

But bear in that it is possible because of Apache Kafka `0.11.0.x` improvements.

Answer (score 2):

Version 2.3 introduced a new class `TopicBuilder` to make creation of such beans more convenient : [configuring-topics](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#configuring-topics)

> If you define a KafkaAdmin bean in your application context, it can
>   automatically add topics to the broker. To do so, you can add a
>   NewTopic @Bean for each topic to the application context. Version 2.3
>   introduced a new class TopicBuilder to make creation of such beans
>   more convenient. The following example shows how to do so:

```
@Bean
public KafkaAdmin admin() {
    Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>();
    configs.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, ...);
    return new KafkaAdmin(configs);
}

@Bean
public NewTopic topic1() {
    return TopicBuilder.name("thing1")
            .partitions(10)
            .replicas(3)
            .compact()
            .build();
}
```